# bq78350R1 distance between pins

Tags: integrated-circuit, surface-mount, texas-instruments

I'm trying to figure out if the [BQ78350R1](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/texas-instruments/BQ78350DBTR-R1/296-44315-1-ND/6110589) has a 0.5mm, 0.6mm or 0.8 mm distance between its pins. I'm staring at the [data-sheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq78350-r1.pdf) but I can't find this information. Thanks for giving me a hand with this.

Comment: Tried the page before the last?

Comment: Dang, I'm such a moron! 0.5 mm.Thanks. Could you please add this as an answer so I can mark it as solved?

Comment: Maybe tag @PlasmaHH so he receives a notification.

Comment: That's a good point. @PlasmaHH please use the answer option so I can mark it as solved. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the page before the last, which shows all important measurements of the chip:

[image]